# Convert result from mysql to list in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

How can I convert the results from Mysql query to a list in python? 
Here is what I've tried so far

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sample_db');
with con:
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT site_id FROM positive_outcomes")

for i in range(cur.rowcount):

    row = cur.fetchone()
    print row[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to listify the entire result set from the cursor object and you should be good

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sample_db');
with con:
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT site_id FROM positive_outcomes")

result_set = list(cursor.fetchall())

for result in result_set:
    # do something here
```

Comment: `fetchall` already returns a list. no need to call `list` on it.

Comment: True, but then comes the decision to whether call all results at once on the client end by `list(...)` or iterate over it row by row. Just as you mentioned in your comment on the question

Comment: @DeepSpace 'fetchall' did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use `fetchone`:

```
def yield_rows():
    for i in range(cur.rowcount):

        row = cur.fetchone()
        yield row[0]

print list(yield_rows())
```